# Dialog custom width height issue

Tags: android, android-dialog

Im trying to assign custom width and height to my custom dialog
,
the code im using works on tablets lolipop and above
but leaves a white patch on top of the dialog on my phone running android kitkat .

[image]

Code snippet

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_documentationissue_notification);
dialog.setCancelable(true);

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = (int) (displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.90);
int height = (int) (displaymetrics.heightPixels * 0.70);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
//dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.NotificationDialogAnimation;
dialog.show();
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before setContentView().

Solution 2:
add custom style

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

then add this line in your manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".youractivity" android:theme="@style/myDialog"></activity>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

You should add **requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)** before **setContentView**.

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT)); //Optional
 dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_documentationissue_notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

That white area is for title,you can hide title this way.

```
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```